# How to get ILoggerFactory in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, iloggerfactory

In `.Net5` `ILoggerFactory` is used as Configure function in `Startup.cs` as follows :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //here we used loggerFactory
    loggerFactory.AddProvider(loggerprovider);
}
```

In `.Net6` how to get it with app or builder

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

OR

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Comment: Use `services.AddLogging()` in your `ConfigureServices` method - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.loggingservicecollectionextensions.addlogging

Comment: @Dai I need ILoggerFactory instance for adding provider like loggerFactory.AddProvider(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`WebApplicationBuilder` exposes [`Logging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder.logging?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property which has [`AddProvider(ILoggingBuilder, ILoggerProvider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggingbuilderextensions.addprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggingBuilderExtensions_AddProvider_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggingBuilder_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggerProvider_) extension method available. Try using it:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddProvider(loggerprovider);
```

Answer (score 10):

To get the actual logger factory instance:

```
var app = builder.Build();
var lf = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

One could also use GetService rather than GetRequiredService. When the service does not exist, GetService returns null and GetRequiredService throws an exception. Pros and cons discussed here:

https://andrewlock.net/the-difference-between-getservice-and-getrquiredservice-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 3):

You can Get ILoggerFactory in dotnet 6 by GetService method in Program.cs class, after builder.Build()

```
var loggerFactory = app.Services.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Applies to .net 6 web api |**
Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.AddLog4Net();
```

Above worked for me in .net 6

1. Check the log file in : \bin\Debug\net6.0 (detail message)
2. Also in event viewer -> Windows logs -> Application (general exception)

Thanks to: https://onloupe.com/blog/does-log4net-work-on-net6/