# How to add Exception handling in logger and stored in Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want when exception throw the exception error show in logger

This is my Controller i add logger in this controller i only add visited page when i visited page that will show in logger the page is visited

```
public class CascadingController : Controller
    {
        private readonly newnewContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<CascadingController> _logger;

        public CascadingController(newnewContext context, ILogger<CascadingController> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            throw new Exception("testing");
            _logger.LogInformation("Index page visited.");
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult Country()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Country Dropdown visited.");
            var cnt = _context.Country.ToList();
            return new JsonResult(cnt);
        }

        public JsonResult State(int id)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("State Dropdown visited.");
            var st = _context.State.Where(e => e.Country.CountryId == id).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(st);
        }

        public JsonResult District(int id)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("District Dropdown visited.");
            var dt = _context.District.Where(e => e.State.StateId == id).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(dt);
        }
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Dropdown()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You like to catch the exception and log the same to database?. And in the Index action exception is thrown before the log statement.

Comment: yes i catch the  exception and log the same to database.and any type of exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `ErrorController` to handle Exception, Refer to this simple Demo:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {

            //log if visit this page
            _logger.LogInformation("Index page visited");

            throw new Exception("This is an Exception");


           
            return View();
        }
```

In `Program.cs`(.Net 6), Configure the ExceptionHandler

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    //configure here
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
```

**ErrorController**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> _logger;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
        public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }


        [Route("Error")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            var exceptionDetails = _context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

            //Here you can save this log in db, I just show it in console
            _logger.LogError($"The Path {exceptionDetails.Path} throw an exception, THe error is {exceptionDetails.Error}");

            
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

**When visit this page, It will log `Index page visted`**

[image]

**After throw an Exception, It will catch the error then log it.**

[image]

Edit====================

Add `Serilog.AspNetCore` NeGet Package

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//.......

var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
{
    config.WriteTo.File($"{path}\\Logs\\Log.txt");
});
```

Comment: and how i stored in database

Comment: Actually, I perfer  to use log file to save the log instead of database, Saving with a database is more complicated than log file.Here is a [tutorie](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-file-logging-to-an-asp-net-core-mvc-application/) about how to achieve it, But If you want to use db to save, You can refer to this [vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnVO-0faYDc)

Comment: okok thnkhu so much

Comment: How i Create `loggerFactory.AddFile($"{path}\\Logs\\Log.txt");` in `program.cs` File

Comment: refer to [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938319/how-to-get-iloggerfactory-in-net-6)

Comment: but how i use addfile in it